# multiply range of value NDVI of Modis product in Google Earth Engine

Tags: modis, ndvi, time-series, google-earth-engine

Modis product have range of value NDVI from -2000 to 10000, but I need this range of value modify on range from -0,2 to 1
This is my code for finding NDVI in region:

```js
var California = ee.Feature(    // California.
    ee.Geometry.Point(-119.37744140625,37.62815420124975),
    {label: 'California'});
var Utah = ee.Feature(  // Utah.
    ee.Geometry.Point(-111.5386962890625,38.1120855331916475),
    {label: 'Utah'});
var Coloredo = ee.Feature(  // Coloredo.
    ee.Geometry.Point(-106.6827392578125,38.98844856696302),
    {label: 'Coloredo'});
var sites = new ee.FeatureCollection([California, Utah, Coloredo]);
Map.addLayer(sites)
var collection = ee.ImageCollection ('MODIS/MOD13Q1')
  .filterDate(ee.Date('2012-01-01'),ee.Date('2014-12-31'))

//function to create mask from SmmaryQA
var maskQA = function(image) {
  return image.updateMask(image.select("SummaryQA").eq(0));
};

var goodCollection = collection.map(maskQA)
Map.addLayer(goodCollection)

//var nas= googCollection.multiply(0.00001)
//var evi1 = function(evi){
  //return evi.updateMask(goodCollection * 0.0001)
//};
//var areaImageSqKm = goodCollection.multiply(0.00001);
//var fallowedArea = fallowed.multiply(areaImageSqKm);  
//var evi2 = collection.map(evi1)

var NDVITimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
    goodCollection, sites, ee.Reducer.mean(),'NDVI', 5000, 'system:time_start', 'label')
        .setChartType('ScatterChart')
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Temporal development of MODIS product',
          vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 1,
        });

print(NDVITimeSeries)
```

How do I recalculate the value range?

Comment: Why do you need to recalculate the range? You could just change the labels in your chart to read -0.2 to 1 instead of -2000 to 10000 and the rest of the chart would not change at all.

Comment: You could improve this question by removing the commented out lines that are note relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new band with a rescaled NDVI values, by mapping a function over the collection:

```js
// Add a rescaled NDVI band to each image in the collection.
goodCollection = goodCollection.map(
  function(img) {
    var rescaled_NDVI = img.select('NDVI')
                           .multiply(0.0001)
                           .rename('NDVI_rescaled');
    return img.addBands(rescaled_NDVI);
  }
);
```

You will then need to update your charting code to use the new band:

```js
var NDVITimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: goodCollection,
    regions: sites,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    band: 'NDVI_rescaled',
    scale: 5000,
    xProperty: 'system:time_start',
    seriesProperty: 'label'
  }).setChartType('ScatterChart')
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Temporal development of MODIS product',
      vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 1,
    });
```

The scaling factor of 0.0001 was obtained from the [USGS MOD13Q1 product page](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod13q1).

Comment: is it not possible in EE to directly change "in-place" a specific band of a multi-band image? It seems that would be very useful, instead of this create a new one + add it back approach?